# Appending html element with jQuery - differences between html, DOM and jQuery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

When appending elements to a page with jQuery, seems I have basically 3 options, summarized here:

```
function  tripleAppend() {
  //1 - append using jQuery, like so:
    var withjquery = $("<p></p>").text("Appending with jquery")
  //2 - Using the html directly formatted:
    var withhtml = "<p>Appending html</p>"
  //3 - Create & append a DOM element:
    var withDOM = document.createElement("p");
  withDOM.innerHTML = "Appending a DOM element"
  //or withDOM.textContent = (....)
  $("body").append(withjquery, withhtml, withDOM)

}
```

Are there important differences between those 3 approaches - any one that is more portable or more limited for a more advanced append? If I'm going to pick one these as my "go-to" solution, any reason to lean for one or the other (saved personal syntactic preferences)?

Comment: `.text()` doesn’t interpret the text as HTML; you would get the same effect by setting `withDOM.textContent` instead of `withDOM.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Whichever one fits your project.**

It's both circumstantial and preferential.

Do you like shorter syntax and the features of the JQuery object? Then use JQuery.
On that note, JQuery *is* a subset of JavaScript, so in the background JQuery is doing the same thing that JavaScript is doing, just with an easier to understand and less cluttered syntax.

One difference between JavaScript `createElement` and `innerHTML`/`JQuery` in your example is that `JQuery` and `innerHTML` both require the provided HTML to be parsed, and then turned into DOM nodes, and *then* appended. Pure JavaScript will always be faster in that scenario,because you are skipping that parsing step, however, it's most likely a negligible difference in performance.

It really all comes down to what you're comfortable with and how concerned you are with optimizing your code for performance - and in this case I would venture to say that if you did decide to use `createElement` because of performance, it could be considered a superfluous optimization.

Comment: Sorry - so DOM wouldn't need to parse the html (since I'm not providing him any) but the other 2 would (since I'm passing it tags which it needs to interpret)? But performance would be negligible in most cases. Do I read that correctly?

Comment: @LogicOnAbstractions exactly.